# How to .submit() while using event.preventDefault() or how to not cancel each other out?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to submit a form after validating the user's ID but, after entering a valid ID the form is not posted:

```
<form action="/register" method="post" id="registerForm">
...
</form>

<script>
        document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
            let input = document.getElementById("username");
            $.get("/check?username=" + input.value, function(data) {
                if (data == false){
                    alert("Username invalid or taken");
                }
                else {
                    alert("success");
                    document.getElementById("registerForm").submit();
                }
            });
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    </script>
```

By changing orientations:

```
<script>
        document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
            let input = document.getElementById("username");
            $.get("/check?username=" + input.value, function(data) {
                if (data == false){
                    alert("Username invalid or taken");
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
                else {
                    alert("success");
                    document.getElementById("registerForm").submit();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The code now allways submits the code. I am not sure if it is event.preventDefault() overrideing .submit() or is it .submit() not functionally as intended.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try `return false` instead of `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: Sorry, didn't work. Putting it in the if statement will always submit and replacing the event.preventDefault() would result in no alert and no submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the event type for addEventListener() "click" to "submit".

Comment: Changing would result in the program not running the entire javascript.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood.  
One of the reason for the issue is the name "submit" of the button.  
Form element has the same name function "submit()".  
So if you name an element "submit", the "submit()" function will be override and cannot call submit function.

Comment: Here is the entire code I tested. This worked fine.

    document.getElementById("submitButton").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        let input = document.getElementById("username");
        $.get("/check?username=" + input.value, function(data) {
            if (data == false){
                alert("Username invalid or taken");
                event.preventDefault();
            }
            else {
                alert("success");
                document.getElementById("registerForm").submit();
            }
        });
    });

Comment: HTML is like this.  
    <form name="registerForm" id="registerForm" action="/xxx">
      <input type="text" id="username">
      <input type="button" id="submitButton" value="Go!">
    </form>

Comment: Additionally, as @Bhuvana Basanth pointed, note that the type and the value of the "data".
Generally the response will be received as string.
Although depending on the server side implementation, you might write like below.
if (data == "false") or if (data == "false\r\n)

Comment: Thanks! I understand how this is a problem now, so basically, don't name the submit button the same as .submit() as it overrides the functionally of it.  Regarding the value of data, the server will send a jsonified boolean value so it isn't a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add the event listener to the whole form and change the event to 'submit'

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the returned data/response type and the message.sometimes, huge issues arises from very insignificant lines

Comment: If I entered a valid username and pressed submit, the check would go through and return true. The console would return: Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).submit is not a function